# How do i reverse the order in a list of strings using iterator?

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

I have created a list of Strings and I need to reverse the order of them using an iterator. This is what I have but it is not working. Can someone please help me find a way to do this or tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class nameList2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        nameList.add("Joey");                                   //list of Strings
        nameList.add("Nicole");
        nameList.add("Lucas");
        nameList.add("Bobby");
        nameList.add("Michelle");
        nameList.add("Allie");

        Iterator<String> nameIterator = nameList.iterator();        //iterator

        for(String s : nameList)                                //for, each loop
        {
            if(nameIterator.hasNext());                         //compile list
                nameIterator.next();
        }

        for(String s: nameList)                                 //for, each loop
        {
            if(nameIterator.hasPrevious());                     //error states method cannot find hasPrevious?
                System.out.println(nameIterator.previous());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do `Collections.reverse(nameList);`?

Comment: use ListIterator instead of Iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **ListIterator** instead of **Iterator** as :

```
ListIterator<String> list = nameList.listIterator(nameList.size());

// Iterate in reverse.
while(list.hasPrevious()) {
  System.out.println(list.previous());
}
```

and you can do also as ***Jonk*** suggested using `Collections.reverse(nameList);`

Answer (score 0):

Use two ListIterators, one at the start, one at the end and swap until they meet.
And don't forget the edge case(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    nameList.add("Joey");                                   //list of Strings
    nameList.add("Nicole");
    nameList.add("Lucas");
    nameList.add("Bobby");
    nameList.add("Michelle");
    nameList.add("Allie");

    ListIterator<String> list = nameList.listIterator();

    System.out.println("Before Reversed\n");

    while(list.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(list.next());
    }

    System.out.println("\nAfter Reversed \n");

    while(list.hasPrevious()){
        System.out.println(list.previous());
    }
}
```